# Trying to get string from HTML input and use it to create new object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I am making a simple application to get stock summary info from Yahoo using a YQL statement to return a JSON.  Thus far, I don't have a lot of code as I am simply trying to establish the basic structure and functionality of the objects I will be working with.  Right now, I just want the user to enter a stock symbol into the input, click submit, and have a JavaScript object created from the Company object that is named as the stock symbol.   I have a text input field and a submit button in HTML and two JavaScript functions

Here is the relevant portion of the HTML

```
<body>
    <form name=formCompanyAdd id='formCompanyAdd'>     
        <input id='inputCompanyAdd' type='text' autofocus/>
        <button id='buttonCompanyAdd' type="submit" onClick="AddCompany();">Add Equity</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
//constructor for prototype object
function Company(symbol){
        this.symbol = symbol;
        };

//function to add new object        
function AddCompany(){
        var symbol = $('#inputCompanyAdd').val();
        console.log(symbol);      //successfully logs correct symbol on the console
        window[symbol] = new Company(symbol);  //but this doesn't happen
        };
```

I have used `window[string] = new Object;` in the past to create new objects with success.  But it isn't working here and I am at a loss.  The only think I am doing differently here than what I have done in the past is binding the function to create the new object to a click event on a html button.  But that should not make a difference, should it?  Do I have a scope issue somehow?  I also tried using `window[symbol] = Object.create(Company);`, but that did not work either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `window[symbol]` ? Do you really want to name your variable dynamically ? Why ?

Comment: Technically, I don't have to.  But I like to do it that way as they are easier to call on that way.  I might try to make each company a subobject of the company object and see if that works.

Comment: Everything seems like it should work fine... Making a fiddle with this code shows it working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/JsCd6/ My guess is the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: That's weird.  It does appear to work on jsfiddle, but if I try to run it from Firefox or Chrome, it doesn't work.  I'm serving it from a local host but I don't see what difference that would make.  I even went to some of my old code to see if similar statements worked in my current development environment and they do.  And I can't see any difference in what I did in those v what I am doing here, other than calling for the function from a click event instead of creating the objects from an array of strings on document load.  Sigh.  Guess, I'll try something different.

Comment: do you really want to pollute the general window object with non-standard things?

Comment: Perhaps you could direct me to what is standard then?  I am just trying to be as object oriented as possible.  Thanks.  I always appreciate good advice.  What is the best general structure for storing a bunch of similar somethings?  Or if there is a better way to create objects with a string stored in a variable, please direct me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem all along had nothing to do with the Javascript and everything to do with the HTML.  For whatever reason having the input and button nested inside a  tag was screwing it up.  All I did was delete the  tag set.  Now that it works, I'll finish my JS and go back and worry about properly forming the HTML form later.  Thanks to those who read this.